# Flash Client AS3 Sockets, C++ Server

Tags: c++, flash

I've been trying out programming Sockets in AS3, but I'm having a bit of a problem.

I'm using a C++ Server and a Flash AS3 client. It's my poor attempt at a first game, so here goes nothing. I have very little programming experience so bear with me please.

This is what I send from the server to client(HEX):

**S** = Packet Size, **C** = Content, **H** = Header(basically telling the client what this packet does)

```
S  H  C..
06 02 00 00 00 00
06 03 D1 13 01 07
02 04
```

However, when my flash client receives the info, it's received this way:

```
S  H  C..
06 02 00 00 00 00
06 03 D1 13 01 07
06 03 D1 13 01 07 -- weird duplicate?
02 04
```

I have no clue why one of the messages is duplicated! I put a trace() in my write function on my C++ server, and it looks like I'm definitely sending it out once, but my Flash client reads it twice.

```
s.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, sData);
function sData(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    while(true){
        try {

            GetByte(); //packet size, im ignoring it for now
            parsePacket();
        }
        catch (error:Error)
        {
            trace(error);
            break;
        }
    }
}
function parsePacket()
{
    var header:uint = GetByte();
    trace("New Packet: ", header);
    switch (header){
        case 0x01:
            //dostuffwithcontent
            break;

        case 0x02:
            //i use it 4 times so there is no "leftover"
            //i actually do stuff with the bytes in real code, but this is only to make it easier to read
            GetByte();GetByte();GetByte();GetByte();
            break;

        case 0x03:
            //this is called twice
            //Flash is reading the same info 2 times from the socket, even though it has only been sent once.
            GetByte();GetByte();GetByte();GetByte();
            break;

        case 0x04:
            trace("last packet received");
            break;

        default:
            break;

    } 
}

function GetByte():uint{return socket_.readUnsignedByte();}
```

This is my C++ function that I use to send the info, I call it once after each "packet".

```
void outputMessage(NetworkMessage& msg)
{
    std::cout << msg.size() << std::endl; //never called more than required, and always shows correct size
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,boost::asio::buffer(msg.getOutputBuffer(), msg.size()),boost::bind(&Session::handle_write, this,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure out why Flash is reading it twice from socket.

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

**Update: Ok, I finally figured out how to sniff localhost traffic on Windows, and as it turns out, the server is sending the message twice, and it's not the client's fault :D The function outputMessage is called only once after every packet is generated, but for some reason, the same packet is still being set out twice. I guess this is a boost related problem, not Flash.**

Update2: I FIXED IT!!! It was a very very silly thing, I didn't even know this is wrong. On server side I had something along the lines of:

```
NetworkMessage msg;
msg.AddByte(0x03);
outputMessage(msg);

NetworkMessage msg;
msg.AddByte(0x04);
outputMessage(msg);
```

Obviously there was an error because both variables have the same name, so instead of just changing the damn name, I tried this(which is obviously wrong, since the program had some weird side effects):

```
{
    NetworkMessage msg;
    msg.AddByte(0x03);
    outputMessage(msg);
}
NetworkMessage msg;
msg.AddByte(0x04);
outputMessage(msg);
```

I feel so silly. I'm really sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: How can I know the length of the message I received? And how can I "unread"? The reason I used a try catch is because I keep reading until it gives an error(meaning: no more to read). I just assumed the sData function won't proc unless the whole message I sent from server is received, and not partially so I didn't bother with checking length of message received. And thanks for the tip about PascalCase.

**Edit: Also both the server and client are local, I doubt WireShark listens for that. I think it needs for the info to pass through the network card?**

Comment: Looked around for a way to sniff localhost traffic on Windows. Trying it now, will report my findings. Maybe the problem is in the server not the client.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured out how to sniff localhost traffic on Windows, and as it turns out, the server is sending the message twice, and it's not the client's fault :D The function outputMessage is called only once after every packet is generated, but for some reason, the same packet is still being set out twice. I guess this is a boost related problem, not Flash.

Comment: How are you writing something this complex with "very little programming experience"??

Comment: @wvxvw: Alright, I understand what you're trying to say and I'll have that part done in a little bit. I'm still facing the problem with the C++ server sending the same message twice, even though boost::asio::async_write is only being called once for that message.

Aerovistae: Copying other project on sourceforge and trial and error mostly.. 99% of the programming I did was using Lua to script missions/quests for a private server for an online game. Learned quite a bit doing that...